# Trouble opening utf-8 URI's with Ruby's 'open-uri'

Tags: ruby, utf-8, google-maps-api-3, escaping, open-uri

I'm trying to get Danish location addresses from google maps web services API with ruby and open-uri.

Trying to get **Ærø, Denmark**: *http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ærø&sensor=false&region=dk* works in Chrome does not with open-uri:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "open-uri"
require 'json'

uri = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ærø&sensor=false&region=dk"
response = open(uri)
array = JSON.parse(response)
pp array
```

Here it yields

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:436:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ærø&sensor=false&region=dk (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Another way of doing it seems to be to escape characters:

```
uri = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ærø&sensor=false&region=dk"
uri_escaped = URI.escape(uri)
response = open(uri_escaped)
array = JSON.parse(response.read)
pp array
```

But this yields an escaped result (which is not sought after :-)

Anyone have any idea what could solve this problem (getting unescaped feedback or sending an utf-8 request)?

Ruby version here is 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Just add

```
require 'string19'
```

to the top of the second example and it works