# Rework ruby 1.8 encoding conversion code to ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

How can I convert the following deprecated ruby 1.8 code into ruby 1.9 code?

```
invalid_chars_stripper = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
invalid_chars_stripper.iconv(body + ' ')[0..-2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does it currently do in 1.9? What do you need it to do?

Comment: It do what it need to do in ruby 1.9: rip out all invalid UTF-8 characters from a string.
But with deprecation warning.

Comment: I found this works well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712096/open-uri-returning-ascii-8bit-from-webpage-encoded-in-iso-8859/14719225#14719225

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
bad_str = "po#{0xFF.chr}ta#{0xFAFAFA.chr}to"        #=> "po?ta?to"
clean_str = bad_str.encode("UTF-8", {:replace=>""}) #=> "potato"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me:

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :033 > bad_str = "pota\xA0to"      
 => "pota\xA0to" 

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :034 > puts bad_str 
pota�to

 => nil 

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :035 > clean_str = bad_str.encode("UTF-8", {:replace=>""})

 => "pota\xA0to"